# OS X terminal login takes lot of time

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app

From earlier this week my MacBook Pro's terminal is taking a lot of time (about 20 seconds) to see the bash prompt.

How do I reduce this time?

**EDIT**: While the login is in progress I tailed the system.log and saw the below output

```
Dec 25 09:28:49 olgunmysql kernel[0]: disk0s3: I/O error.
Dec 25 09:28:49 olgunmysql kernel[0]: 
Dec 25 09:28:49 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 25 09:28:49 olgunmysql.local login[1124]: in pam_sm_acct_mgmt(): OpenDirectory -             
Membership cache TTL set to 1800.
Dec 25 09:28:49 olgunmysql.local login[1124]: in od_record_check_pwpolicy(): retval: 0
Dec 25 09:28:49 olgunmysql.local login[1124]: in od_record_attribute_create_cfstring():  
returned 2 attributes for dsAttrTypeStandard:AuthenticationAuthority
Dec 25 09:28:49 olgunmysql.local login[1124]: USER_PROCESS: 1124 ttys001
```

Comment: Do you remember what you did before that? Did you change anything in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`? You obviously run MySQL, have you tried disabling that?

Comment: Nope. No change performed. This is happening for about 1 week where mysql has been installed for about 3 or 4 months before. I also checked the disk disk0s3 which is the system disk. I repaired the permissions. It's kinda weird problem.

Comment: The messages only show one specific point in time. Is there anything before or after that? Do the problems persist if you load another shell (e.g. `zsh`)? Do you get the same behavior with another user account? Tried rebooting (I sometimes forget that as well)?

Comment: Have you tried [removing asl files or changing the login command](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/how-do-i-speed-up-new-terminal-tab-loading-time)?

Comment: Might be related to [open directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220838/slow-login-and-terminal-loading-time-in-yosemite-possibly-related-to-open-direc).

Answer (score 0):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/how-do-i-speed-up-new-terminal-tab-loading-time

this has solved my problem.
To solve the problem : I just changed the terminal startup config to `/usr/bin/bash` instead of `/usr/bash`.